# How to know which attributes to use with different properties?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I know weak means not retained and strong means retained,nonatomic is fast, but not thread safe while atomic is slower but thread safe. However, I do not why or which one to use under different circumstance. Is there a tutorial showing which attributes to use with certain properties?

```
  @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
```

Here is an example code of what I am talking about just in case anyone is lost. I know to use weak and nonatomic for interface objects.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html) tutorial it is very good and read [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) and this [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html
](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-Transitioning